# Unity Container Register and resolve for generic Interface with inheritance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following code :

```
 public interface IGenericDao<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity {    }

 public interface IEntity { }

 public abstract class AbstractEntity : IEntity {}

 public interface IMasterEntity : IEntity {}

 public interface IDynamicEntity : IEntity {}

 public class Client : AbstractEntity , IMasterEntity {} 

 public class MasterEntityHandler<TEntity> : IGenericDao<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : IMasterEntity {}

 public class DynamicEntityHandler<TEntity> : IGenericDao<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : IDynamicEntity {}
```

In the unity container, I made the registration as :

```
container.RegisterType<IGenericDao<IMasterEntity>, MasterEntityHandler<IMasterEntity>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IGenericDao<IDynamicEntity>, MasterEntityHandler<IDynamicEntity>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

When trying to resolve with Client class with

```
container.Resolve<IGenericDao<Client>>();
```

I am getting an error that

> ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   Unity.ResolutionFailedException: The current type,
>   Interface.IGenericDao`1[Client],
>   is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?

Tried this registration also, but still same error :

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericDao<IMasterEntity>),typeof(MasterEntityHandler<>)
                , new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericDao<IDynamicEntity>),typeof(DynamicEntityHandler<>)
                    , new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

and also :

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericDao<>),typeof(MasterEntityHandler<IMasterEntity>)
                , new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericDao<>),typeof(DynamicEntityHandler<IDynamicEntity>)
                    , new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider narrowing the scope of the interfaces

```
public interface IMasterDao<TEntity> : IGenericDao<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : IMasterEntity { }

public interface IDynamicDao<TEntity>: IGenericDao<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : IDynamicEntity {}

public class MasterEntityHandler<TEntity> : IMasterDao<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : IMasterEntity {}

public class DynamicEntityHandler<TEntity> : IDynamicDao<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : IDynamicEntity {}
```

Remove the interface from the registration and leave it as an open generic registration.

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IMasterDao<>), typeof(MasterEntityHandler<>), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType(typeof(IDynamicDao<>), typeof(DynamicEntityHandler<>), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

The type constraint on the implementation will handle what classes can be used.

Comment: I have two different handlers, I edited the questions with the same. If I use the above solution, the container only takes the latest registration done.

Comment: Narrowing the scope of the interface makes the design more simple. Thanks for pointing this out.  I was going in the wrong way of using a kind of proxy without a switch.

Comment: How would you call this from the constructor?